# highcharts timestamp convert to human readable datetime

Tags: highcharts

I have the attached highchart and timestamp is displayed as received from DB. I need somehow to convert it to human readable but without success. [highchart](https://pasteboard.co/I6kcjxI.png)

```
      xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    categories: labels,
    formatter: function () {
      return "mydate: " + moment.utc(moment.unix(this.x/1000)).format("DD/MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss") + "<br> myspeed: " + this.y;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `formatter` option must be nested in `labels`, not in `xAxis` : https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    categories: labels,
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return "mydate: " + moment.utc(moment.unix(this.x/1000)).format("DD/MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss") + "<br> myspeed: " + this.y;
        }
    }
}
```